# 10 Minutes to Pandas tutorial - to_numpy() does not exist?

Tags: python, numpy

Following: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html 
This - df.to_numpy() throws an AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Not sure why.

Comment: This was due to change in version; use `pip install pandas==1.0.3`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This feature was just added in Version 0.24.0, which was released a couple of days ago.  If you haven't updated yet, the attribute doesn't exist!  Once you update pandas the problem should resolve itself.

Comment: For others, to explain both comments: (I guess) that markuscosinus answer works for versions of pandas prior to 0.24.0, and Owen L.'s answer works for the latest version. Upgrade can be performed via conda or the GUI.

Answer (score 29):

Try `df.values` instead. This will have the same effect for versions of pandas prior to 0.24.0

Answer (score 13):

To check your version of pandas

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
```

If it's not 0.24, you need to update pandas else you can use `df.values`.
To upgrade pandas under Anaconda, grab Anaconda command prompt and type:

```
conda update pandas
```

To upgrade pandas under Python3

```
pip3 install --upgrade pandas
```

One really great thing with `to_numpy()` method is the `copy` parameter it provides:

```
npa=df.to_numpy() #editing npa will reflect in df
npa=to_numpy(copy=True) #editing npa will not affect the df
```

Answer (score -1):

Need to update Pandas 0.24.0s to use df.values() and df.to_numpy()

Comment: `df.values` or `df.values()`? For the latter, there is no such method in `pandas==0.23.4`; I believe it should be the former

Comment: df.values,not df.values().

Comment: This answer provides nothing new and is also wrong.