# Selecting multiple columns, both consecutive and non-consecutive, in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select

I am trying to run the following:

```
X = d.iloc[:, [13, 30, 35:45]].values
```

It fails at the range 35:45.

PS: There is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe) with many useful answers, but they don't address the issue of getting both consecutive and non-consecutive columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.r_`:

```
import numpy as np
X = d.iloc[:, np.r_[13, 30, 35:45]].to_numpy()
```

Intermediate output of `np.r_[13, 30, 35:45]`:

```
array([13, 30, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44])
```

Comment: Let me add that instead of "to_numpy()", for earlier pandas versions it will be "values". As per the relevant answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54424818/10-minutes-to-pandas-tutorial-to-numpy-does-not-exist